# Creating a minimum output matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there an easy way to do something like this in matlab:

I have a matrix

```
t2 = [0.4366 0.4298 0.5907;
      0.9401 0.5358 0.6136;
      0.2305 0.5212 0.9759;
      0.9545 0.5572 0.9042];

t2 = [ 0      0.4298   0.5907
       0      0        0
       0,2305 0        0
       0      0        0 ]
```

I want to output zeros at the place of the elements that are not minimum at each column, and output the minimum elements at their correct positions.

Comment: @jdl there are no 0 elements in the original matrix

Comment: Actually, i want to get the second matrix from the first matrix, starting from the top.

Comment: use t3(find(t2(:,1)<minVal))=0; build upon per column

Comment: It just deletes certain values, but not all of them.

Comment: `z=bsxfun(@eq,t2,min(t2));t2(~z)=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t2 = [0.4366 0.4298 0.5907;
      0.9401 0.5358 0.6136;
      0.2305 0.5212 0.9759;
      0.9545 0.5572 0.9042];

[~,idx]=min(t2);
n=sub2ind(size(t2), idx, 1:size(t2,2));
mask=zeros(size(t2));
mask(n)=1;
t2=t2.*mask

t2 =

   0.00000   0.42980   0.59070
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.23050   0.00000   0.00000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = t2 .* bsxfun(@eq, t2, min(t2));
```

Comment: Definitely the most elegant approach for this problem.

Comment: Nice. As with most of your answers, this makes another piece of the `bsxfun` puzzle click into place for me.